# Railscasts #71: Routing error when trying to pass parameters in post method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, controller, rspec2, rails-routing

I am using RSpec-2 to test my controller and I am seeing weird behavior.
Essentially I am doing the same as in [Railscasts #71](http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec)

```
describe DeliverablesController do
  describe "responding to POST create" do
    describe "with valid parameters" do
      it "should pass the params to the deliverable item" do
        post :create, :deliverable => {:title => "Some Deliverable"}
        assigns[:deliverable].title.should == "Some Deliverable"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which results in the following error:

```
  1) DeliverablesController responding to POST create with valid parameters should pass the params to the deliverable item
     Failure/Error: post :create, :deliverable => {:title => "Some Deliverable"}
     ActionController::RoutingError:
     No route matches {:deliverable=>{:title=>"Some Deliverable"}, :controller=>"deliverables", :action=>"create"}
```

Obviously `:deliverable` should not be part of the route but written into `params`. My problem starts with not being sure which `post` method is called.

My Gemfile.lock can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/961768).

---

**EDIT**

And my routes.rb can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/962329).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is good to bounce off ideas: My problem was that I am in a nested route basically doing the following.

```
resources :projects do
    resources :deliverables
end
```

The error message threw me off, the real problem was that I did not provide a `project_id`. I fixed it by doing

```
post :create, :project_id => 11, :deliverable => {:title => "Some Deliverable"}
```

instead of

```
post :create, :deliverable => {:title => "Some Deliverable"}
```

Thank you, hammar!